# Где здесь поставить запятые? Старого лесника не страшили

Tags: пунктуация, егэ

Старого лесника не страшили нехоженые тропы и глубокие пещеры и не пугала встреча с дикими животными.

(Расставьте запятые)

Comment: Только при наличии своего варианта. И с объяснением.

Не собес.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые не нужны: однородные члены предложения, соединенные союзом "и".
Не страшили и не пугала.
Нехоженые тропы и глубокие пещеры.